# Evaluate Value at Each Step of a Chained Promise and Break Out of Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have the following chained promise. At each step, I need to evaluate if the returned value is not null. I can add an if else condition at each step, but I was wondering if there is a more concise way of doing this. Also, how can I break out of the chain if the value is null at any step?

```
       axios.post('/api/login', accounts)
        .then((response) => {
          this.nonce = response.data
          return this.nonce
        }).then((nonce) => {
          let signature = this.signing(nonce)
          return signature
        }).then((signature) => {
          this.verif(signature)
        })
        .catch((errors) => {
          ...
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You break out of the promise chain by throwing an error:

```
       axios.post('/api/login', accounts)
        .then((response) => {
          this.nonce = response.data
          return this.nonce
        }).then((nonce) => {
          if (!nonce) throw ("no nonce")
          let signature = this.signing(nonce)
          return signature
        }).then((signature) => {
          if (!signature) throw ("no signature")
          this.verif(signature)
        })
        .catch((errors) => {
          ...
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested promise is unnecessary. Try this

```
axios.post('/api/login', accounts)
        .then(async (response) => {
          this.nonce = response.data
          let signature = await this.signing(this.nonce);
          if(!signature){
            throw "invalid"
          }
          this.verif(signature);
        .catch((errors) => {
          ...
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer vpdiongzon.

Answer (score 1):

conciseness it can likely be one `.then()` as for the check breaking out with a throw on any null value.

```js
axios.post('/api/login', accounts)
        .then(async (response) => {
          if(!response.data) throw "Response Error"
          this.nonce = response.data

          const signature = await this.signing(this.nonce);
          if(!signature) throw "invalid"
          
          this.verif(signature)
         })
        .catch((errors) => {
          ...
        })
```

Comment: no problem! If that doesn't work let me know I am sure we can figure it out! :)